# C++ How to print unicode character over 0xFFFF?

Tags: c++, unicode

I'm trying to print all chinese character with c++.
my project uses wchar_t for handling unicode string.

wikipedia said: chinese chars are located in:
4E00–62FF
6300–77FF
7800–8CFF
8D00–9FFF
3400–4DBF
20000–215FF
21600–230FF
23100–245FF
24600–260FF
26100–275FF
27600–290FF
29100–2A6DF
2A700–2B73F
2B740–2B81F
2B820–2CEAF
2CEB0–2EBEF
30000–3134F

but my code said wchar_t is 2byte.
this means wchar_t support 0x0000 - 0xFFFF.
how can I print unicode char over 0xFFFF? should I use another thing (such as wstring?) rather than wchar_t?

thanks in advance.

Comment: @Asesh: can you figure how many bytes does a `char16_t` contain? My own guess is close to 2...

Comment: Wide characters have no reason to be more constrained than narrow ones, so you have to know what encoding is used. If you use UCS2 you cannot represent Unicode characters above 0xFFFF. If you use UTF16, characters of code above 0xFFFF or between 0xD800 and 0xDFFF will use two `wchar_t` characters (as you implementation uses 16 bits wide characters).

Comment: Read up on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Code_points_from_U+010000_to_U+10FFFF and "surrogate pairs", and then see how that applies with what you're using to print characters.

Comment: There is also [char32_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#char32_t) in C++11 and later.  The other relevant factors is what does your platform support, or is your output going to a text file, or programmatically creating a structured text output file like HTML.

Comment: @SergeBallesta oops I meant char32_t, my bad

Comment: ^ ^ thank you all, really appreciated.

Comment: You can simply use UTF-8 (and so char). The problem is not on C++, but on how the data is interpreted by the operating system/console/toolkit/. (but so you lose the semantic of characters)